# Spring transaction + hibernate class cast exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, session

I started to use openSessionInViewFilter for managing my session. I annotated my service method as @Transactional for clossing session, but following exception started to appear. This exception is raised when my annotated service method ends, which could be seen in stacktrace also. I'am using `Spring 3, Hibernate 3, jsf 1.2`.

Stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2558)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2494)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2821)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:145)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:924)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:737)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.getListOfPrescriptions(Unknown Source)
    at cz.generali.benefits.bean.TranscriptionBean.getPrescriptions(TranscriptionBean.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:171)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:1389)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getValue(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1647)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:65)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable.createDataModel(UIDataTable.java:121)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:621)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getRowIndex(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.idsAreEqual(_ComponentUtils.java:136)
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:465)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:1072)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:1079)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findComponentFor(RendererUtils.java:1042)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findComponentFor(RendererUtils.java:1014)
    at org.richfaces.component.util.HtmlUtil.expandIdSelector(HtmlUtil.java:75)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.ComponentControlRendererBase.replaceClientIds(ComponentControlRendererBase.java:90)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.ComponentControlRendererBase.writeScript(ComponentControlRendererBase.java:122)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ComponentControlRenderer.doEncodeEnd(ComponentControlRenderer.java:129)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ComponentControlRenderer.doEncodeEnd(ComponentControlRenderer.java:136)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:134)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:649)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChild(RendererUtils.java:534)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChildren(RendererUtils.java:511)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlLinkRendererBase.encodeChildren(HtmlLinkRendererBase.java:144)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:627)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolBarGroupRenderer.renderChild(ToolBarGroupRenderer.java:74)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolBarGroupRenderer.encodeChildren(ToolBarGroupRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:627)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolBarRendererBase.encodeChildren(ToolBarRendererBase.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:627)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:250)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:257)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at cz.generali.benefits.util.UserLogFilter.doFilter(UserLogFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at cz.generali.benefits.security.UserProfileStubFilter.doFilter(UserProfileStubFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at cz.generali.benefits.security.FirstLoginFilter.doFilter(FirstLoginFilter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

part of my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

`Service`

```
@Service("zukService")
@Transactional
public class ZukServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements ZukService {

    @Autowired
    private DuniversalBenefitsPrescriptionDAO prescriptionDAO;

    @Override
    public List<DuniversalBenefitsPrescription> getListOfPrescriptions(final BenefitsSearchPrescriptionCriteria criteria) {
        final List<DuniversalBenefitsPrescription> transcriptionList = prescriptionDAO
                .getPaymentPrescriptionsByZukAndDate(criteria);
        return transcriptionList;
        //IN THIS PLACE PROBLEM OCCUR
    }
}
```

DuniversalBenefitsPrescription

```
 public class DuniversalBenefitsPrescription implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Long id;
        private Integer zukNumber;
        private String policyNumber;
        private String insureeName;
        private String insureeSurname;
        private Long identificationNumber;
        private Double amountFromEmployer;
        private Double amountFromEmployee;
        private Date insuranceDate;
        private Short frequency;
        private Date validFrom;
        private Date validTo;
        private Short opken1;
        private Short opken2;
        private Short opken3;
        private Double totalAmount;
        private Long startOfBenefit;
        private Long endOfZukValidity;
        private String proposalNumber;
        private Date dueDate;
        private String buyoutTerm;

    ..getters and setters
    }
```

HBM.xml

```
   <hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="cz.generali.czgpolinfo.dao.syn.DuniversalBenefitsPrescription">
            <subselect>
            SELECT 
            PLAT.ID AS ID,ZUK.ZUKNR,SML.VB,SML.POLNR,SML.ZAHLART,COR.FIZAHL,PLAT.GESAMTBETRAG,COR.KLIZAHL,OS.RDC,
            OS.FAMNAME,OS.VORNAME,PLAT.OPKENN1,PLAT.OPKENN2,PLAT.OPKENN3,PLAT.PRAEMIEVON,PLAT.PRAEMIEBIS,ZUK.WERTVON,ZUK.WERTBIS,SML.FREMDPOLNR,SML.BEZBIS,RP.TEXT
            FROM ...
        </subselect>


      <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
       <column name="ID"/>
       <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="zukNumber" type="java.lang.Integer">
       <column name="ZUKNR"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="policyNumber" type="java.lang.String">
       <column name="POLNR"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="insureeName" type="java.lang.String">
       <column name="VORNAME"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="insureeSurname" type="java.lang.String">
       <column name="FAMNAME"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="identificationNumber" type="java.lang.Long">
       <column name="RDC"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="amountFromEmployer" type="java.lang.Double">
       <column name="FIZAHL"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="amountFromEmployee" type="java.lang.Double">
       <column name="KLIZAHL"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="insuranceDate" type="java.util.Date">
       <column name="VB"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="frequency" type="java.lang.Short">
       <column name="ZAHLART"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="validFrom" type="java.util.Date">
       <column name="PRAEMIEVON"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="validTo" type="java.util.Date">
       <column name="PRAEMIEBIS"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="opken1" type="java.lang.Short">
       <column name="OPKENN1"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="opken2" type="java.lang.Short">
       <column name="OPKENN2"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="opken3" type="java.lang.Short">
       <column name="OPKENN3"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="totalAmount" type="java.lang.Double">
       <column name="GESAMTBETRAG"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="startOfBenefit" type="java.lang.Long">
       <column name="WERTVON"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="endOfZukValidity" type="java.lang.Long">
       <column name="WERTBIS"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="proposalNumber" type="java.lang.String">
       <column name="FREMDPOLNR"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="dueDate" type="java.util.Date">
       <column name="BEZBIS"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="buyoutTerm" type="java.lang.String">
       <column name="TEXT"/>
      </property>
     </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

TranscriptionBean

```
  @Component
    @Scope(value = "request")
    public class TranscriptionBean extends BaseBean {

        @Autowired
        private SessionBean sessionBean;
        @Autowired
        private ZukService zukService;


        private BenefitsSearchPrescriptionCriteria prescriptionCriteria = new BenefitsSearchPrescriptionCriteria(
                DEFAULT_ORDER_PROPERTY);

        public List<DuniversalBenefitsPrescription> getPrescriptions() {
            List<DuniversalBenefitsPrescription> prescriptionList = new ArrayList<DuniversalBenefitsPrescription>();
            final boolean criteriaSet = setSearchCriteria();
            if (criteriaSet) {
                prescriptionList = zukService.getListOfPrescriptions(prescriptionCriteria);
                sessionBean.setItemsFound(prescriptionList.size());
                checkSendEditedPeriod();
            }

            for (final DuniversalBenefitsPrescription transcription : prescriptionList) {
                polNrs.add(transcription.getPolicyNumber());
            }
            return prescriptionList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show what's relevant from the stacktrace, i.e. `TranscriptionBean` and the entity it manages.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll I edited my posted, adding some relevant code.

Comment: @Zdend the exception is caused you have given `Date` type instead of `Long`, i think may be in `BenefitsSearchPrescriptionCriteria` class. and no need of everything to post, keep classes related to exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved my problem (`mutable="false"`) :)

http://blog.xebia.com/2009/04/06/why-did-hibernate-update-my-database/

http://java-success.blogspot.cz/2013/01/hibernate-automatic-dirty-checking-of.html

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="cz.generali.czgpolinfo.dao.syn.DuniversalBenefitsPrescription" mutable="false">
...
```